# Jade equivalent of <%= %>

Tags: express, pug

I'm trying to implement toastr notifications on my express application using express-toastr (https://github.com/kamaln7/express-toastr). The documentation says that after including the following in the controller:

```
 if (err)
 {
 req.toastr.error('Invalid credentials.');
 } else {
 req.toastr.success('Successfully logged in.', "You're in!");
 }
```

we have to include the libraries in the on the views. That is okay. But we also have to include something like this :

```
<%= req.toastr.render() %>
```

What is the equivalent of this on jade?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:
    div #{req.toastr.render()}

related post: https://www.filosophy.org/post/34/using_javascript_functions_within_the_jade_templating_language/

Comment: Your link is broken.